# No Space Left on Device when transferring large amount of photos to newly formated HDD

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, hard-drive, storage

So I am struggling mightily as a new Ubuntu user, so first off please forgive my newbie ignorance. The issue that I am running into is that I have 63,000 images I am trying to transfer from a thumb drive to a 4TB hard drive in my home desktop which is running Ubuntu 20. I can see that the drive is not full by using

```
sudo df | grep -v /snap
```

And I don't think I am out of inodes as the drive was just formated in FAT yesterday.

[Storage showing 3% and inodes are blank as the drive is in FAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROc5M.png)

```
tim@Tower:/mnt/backup$ df | grep -v /snap
Filesystem      1K-blocks       Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev              6099212          0    6099212   0% /dev
tmpfs             1225752       2144    1223608   1% /run
/dev/sda5       959862832  432270140  478764532  48% /
tmpfs             6128756          0    6128756   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5120          4       5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs             6128756          0    6128756   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1          523248          4     523244   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs             1225748         44    1225704   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdf1       117766024   71007812   40733000  64% /media/tim/McNellies
/dev/sdb1      2146959360   44987200 2101972160   3% /mnt/backup
/dev/sdc1      1953036576 1327782336  625254240  68% /media/tim/Media
/dev/sde1      2146959360   22655104 2124304256   2% /media/tim/D2E8-1097
tim@Tower:/mnt/backup$ df -i | grep -v /snap
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            1524803    711  1524092    1% /dev
tmpfs           1532189   1325  1530864    1% /run
/dev/sda5      61022208 280043 60742165    1% /
tmpfs           1532189      1  1532188    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1532189      5  1532184    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1532189     18  1532171    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1             0      0        0     - /boot/efi
tmpfs           1532189     95  1532094    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdf1       7512064  68657  7443407    1% /media/tim/McNellies
/dev/sdb1             0      0        0     - /mnt/backup
/dev/sdc1             0      0        0     - /media/tim/Media
/dev/sde1             0      0        0     - /media/tim/D2E8-1097
tim@Tower:/mnt/backup$
```

Based on a few other posts here on AskUbuntu I tried remounting the drive, I formated it from Ext4 over to FAT and also told it to erase the drive while formating. Finally remouted the drive again but this time I mounted it at /mtn/backup instead of mounting it at /media just in case the issue was that /media was out of inodes.

I know the drive has space, though it is showing 2.2TB free rather than the full 4TB, which is another issue but I am not sure it is the root cause. Any idea what I am going wrong here? I really need to back up these photos so I can get the card back to a Raspberry Pie for a computer vision project.

Comment: Does the FAT formatted drive have subfolders or all files are copied to the top folder of the drive? As far as I remember, FAT filesystem has some limit on number of directory entries in the top folder, while it doesn't have any such limits in the subfolders.

Comment: So right now there is just two folders, img and box_img each of which are copied over from the thumbdrive and should have 31,000 jpg images each, but somewhere around 21k into the first folder I get the error that I have no more space.

Comment: Excluding the `/snap` directory from the results (with `grep -v /snap`) was not a good idea. You may find that it's now a mixture of some of your photo directories and some snap packages.

Comment: Your FAT filesystem may be limited to 2TiB (unless you used 4KiB sectors for 16TiB).

Answer (score 0):

It might be as simple as a very unfortunate choice of names: `/snap` is used on recent Ubuntu releases as the system directory for *snap packages*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap_(package_manager)

Try a different name like `/photos`. Or, more conforming to Linux standards, create a subdirectory in your home directory; your home directory is yours alone, it doesn't collide with system directories.

```
cd
mkdir photos
```

(a lone `cd` without argument takes you to your home directory)